# Why does my android launcher re-open on Home Press

Tags: android, homescreen, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I'm developing a launcher application. When I'm on the launcher, and I press home, the activity animates away and opens a new instance of the activity. What can I do to just stay on the home screen activity when pressing home?

```
<application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the activity's launchMode to "singleTask" or "singleTop" resolved this issue.